# Saving the query results without appending it to an existing table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I have a table ***road*** that inludes `gid`and `geom` columns and an empty column `distance`. 
Using the script below:

```
INSERT INTO road (distance) 
SELECT ST_length(a.geom::geography,true)/1000 
FROM road a;
```

I only get the results appended to the existing ***road*** table. And I was wondering if there is a way to save my query results from the beginning of the `distance` column so they will correspond to the existing `gid`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably are looking for update?

```
update road set distance =  ST_length(geom::geography,true)/1000;
```

try it within a transaction to be able to rollback:

```
begin;
    update road set distance =  ST_length(geom::geography,true)/1000;
    select * from road; --to check the result
rollback; -- or commit if you like it
```

Comment: 1. The first suggestion doesn't give the right results: In fact all my ***distance*** cell show the same result, which doesn't correspond by the way to the results that I haveusing directly the query `SELECT ST_length(a.geom::geography,true)/1000 ` (The treatment time is anomaly long as well).
2. The second one shows the error message ERROR: `syntax error at or near "select" LINE 3: select * from road; --to check the result ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 85`

Comment: the both 1 and 2 is one suggestion. you probably ran them one by one (no semicomma, thus syntax error), which is sad. the first statement should gove you the idea, the second should show how to implement it...

Comment: Add a semicolon after 1000, will solve your syntax error
begin;
    update road set distance =  ST_length(geom::geography,true)/1000; 
    select * from road; --to check the result
rollback;

Comment: The `update ` Command worked today. I guess it was a problem when refreshing my tables; Thnks for your help